# Price Comparison Engine using WSO2 products

Tags: wso2, drools, rule-engine, business-rules, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB for an aggregation project. We are getting prices for some products using SOAP from six vendors, response formats are already unified in ESB and each response contains 5-10 products.
Here's some sample responses:

**Response from Vendor1:**

```
<Products Vendor="1stVendor">
    <Product>
        <Brand>Sony</Brand>
        <Model>M5<Model> 
        <Price>800.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product>
        <Brand>Dell</Brand>
        <Model>B6<Model> 
        <Price>900.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product>
        <Brand>IBM</Brand>
        <Model>H9<Model> 
        <Price>950.00<Price>
    <Product>
<Products>
```

**Response from Vendor2:**

```
<Products Vendor="2ndVendor">
    <Product>
        <Brand>Sony</Brand>
        <Model>M5<Model> 
        <Price>720.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product>
        <Brand>Dell</Brand>
        <Model>B6<Model> 
        <Price>950.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product>
        <Brand>IBM</Brand>
        <Model>H9<Model> 
        <Price>940.00<Price>
    <Product>
<Products>
```

Now we need to compare the prices for each product to find the cheapest price for each product and return the best options as the final response. 
For the above examples, it should look like this:

```
<Products>
    <Product CheapestVendor="2ndVendor">
        <Brand>Sony</Brand>
        <Model>M5<Model> 
        <Price>720.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product CheapestVendor="1stVendor">
        <Brand>Dell</Brand>
        <Model>B6<Model> 
        <Price>900.00<Price>
    <Product>
    <Product CheapestVendor="2ndVendor">
        <Brand>IBM</Brand>
        <Model>H9<Model> 
        <Price>940.00<Price>
    <Product>
<Products>
```

With regards to the above details:

1- What's the best/fastest strategy to implement this? 
2- Can we use WSO2 BRS (Business Rules Server) as a price comparison engine to achieve this? If yes, should we merge all responses into one message and pass to BRS or the messages have to be sent separately. 
3- Do we need WSO2 BPS (or any BPEL engine) for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and (for me) the easiest would be for me to do it with in the Esb.
If you have lot of complicated business logic/rules bringing BRS 
Into the picture makes sense. On the other hand if you have 
Workflows which might take a long time to complete etc its a usecase for BPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 ESB to compare the two results. ESB contains with several [mediators](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Mediators) that can help you. With ESB, you can get the inflow and filter values using filter mediator.

```
<filter source="//Product/Price" regex=".*/Price.*">
      <then>
          <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
          <drop/>
      </else>
</filter>
```

Once you filtered two inflow's Pricing values, name them using property mediator. Then you can filter again two values to find the smallest value of the two.